# error when converting base64 String to decimal

Tags: java, base64

The method below convert a decimal to `BASE64` string:

```
public static String id2base64String(String mediaId) {
    String postId = "";
    try {
        long id = Long.parseLong(mediaId);
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";

        while (id > 0) {
            long remainder = (id % 64);
            id = (id - remainder) / 64;
            postId = alphabet.charAt((int) remainder) + postId;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("input is %s, output is %s", mediaId, postId));
    return postId;
}
```

And I wrote a method to reverse the function so that it can take a `BASE64` string to a decimal:

```
public static String base64StringToId(String base64String) {
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";
    long id = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < base64String.length(); i++) {
        char c = base64String.charAt(i);
        int i1 = alphabet.indexOf(c);
        id += i1 * Math.pow(64, base64String.length() - 1 - i);
        //converted[string.length() - i - 1] = i1;
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("input is %s, output is %s", base64String, String.valueOf(id)));
    return String.valueOf(id);
}
```

When using the following code to run:

```
    String base64String = "ybyPRoQWzX";
    String id = "908540701891980503";
    id2base64String(id);
    base64StringToId(base64String);
```

It shows output as:

```
input is 908540701891980503, output is ybyPRoQWzX
input is ybyPRoQWzX, output is 908540701891980544
```

As you can see the second method output is not as expected (expected to be `908540701891980503`, but I got `908540701891980544`).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small error in floating-point operations with large numbers. I think writing this way gets more consistent.

```
public static String base64StringToId(String base64String) {
    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";
    long id = 0L;
    for (int i = 0; i < base64String.length(); i++) {
        char c = base64String.charAt(i);
        int i1 = alphabet.indexOf(c);
        id = (id * 64) + i1;
        //id += i1 * Math.pow(64, base64String.length() - 1 - i);
        //converted[string.length() - i - 1] = i1;
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("input is %s, output is %s", base64String, String.valueOf(id)));
    return String.valueOf(id);
}
```